# linux/unix command for checking the outside/inside network connections

Tags: linux, ssh, networking, command-line, security

From my local machine, which command can tell me which machines I have connected via ssh, or ftp, etc? At the same time, which command can let me know which machines have tried to connect my machine via these different network protocols?

Answer (score 2):

To check which port or address your computer is connected to try

```
sudo lsof -i
sudo netstat -l
```

Comment: The OP could also use `ss` (socket status) to see current connections.

Comment: @Schives you are right sudo netstat ss displays current connections.